# Delete string between 2 special strings on every line in file

Tags: shell, sed, awk, grep

Using awk I need find characters between first "." and first space " " (if exists) and replace it with space " ".
I have file (test.txt) with this structure:

```
asdf.test.com 04-05-2014  
qwer.test1.test.com 04-05-2014  
asdfgg 04-05-2014  
sadf  
asdff.com 04-05-2014
```

I need this output:

```
asdf 04-05-2014  
qwer  04-05-2014  
asdfgg  04-05-2014  
sadf  
asdff  04-05-2014
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk NF=NF FS='\\..+ ' test.txt
```

Result

```
asdf 04-05-2014
qwer 04-05-2014
asdfgg 04-05-2014
sadf
asdff 04-05-2014
```

Comment: in CYGWIN, gawk v4, I didn't get the right answer with it. Column 2 is lost in result.

Comment: Know the reason now, the original file has white space in end of each line.

Comment: This will also remove any empty/blank line.

Comment: Will not work, as BMW pointed out, there are space at end of the line and .* is greedy and will remove data that is required.  This will work `awk NF=NF FS='\\.[^ ]+ ' file`

Answer (score 2):

Using sed, which can fix the issue that space in end of line.

```
sed 's/\.[^. ]*//g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Try sed:

```
cat test.txt | sed 's/\..*\ / /g'
```

Comment: Except without a [useless use of `cat`](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html).

Comment: You do not need to escape the space, you can use: `sed 's/\..* / /g'`

Comment: Will not work, as BMW pointed out, there are space at end of the line and `.* ` is greedy and will remove data that is required.  this will work `sed 's/\.[^ ]* / /g' test.txt` . PS Never cat a file to program that can read it itself.

Answer (score -1):

This should do:

```
awk '{sub(/\..*/,x,$1)}8' test.txt
asdf04-05-2014
qwer04-05-2014
asdfgg 04-05-2014
sadf
asdff04-05-2014
```

Updated as suggested by BMW, since there are blank at end of line.

---

or this:

```
awk -F"[. ]" '{print $1,(NF>1?$NF:x)}' test.txt
asdf 04-05-2014
qwer 04-05-2014
asdfgg 04-05-2014
sadf
asdff 04-05-2014
```

Comment: should be `awk '{sub(/\..*/," ",$1)}8' file`, if use your code, I get same error as @Steven Penny's, no column 2 in result. (the reason is, the original file has white space in end of line.)

Comment: @BMW No, this will make the greedy `.*` remove all to the end of the line. It need  the single space to know where to stop.  Using your code, it only prints text before first `.` except for this line  `asdfgg 04-05-2014`

Comment: $1 in sub(), not $0, so it will not remove all after dot. And no need replace to space as well: `awk '{sub(/\..*/,"",$1)}8' file`

Comment: @BMW  Need some sleep. Did not see that.  Both solution should work. I have no problem with my solution.

Comment: when you try to edit OP's question, then you will see there are spaces in end of each line, so with your solution, `.* ` will match to end of line. that's why it gets all replaced after dot.